# How to update to the last version in mercurial after adding new files?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs

I've created a repository in the project's directory. I've added all the files and made some commits. Then I added new files to project and to repository. After that I returned to earlier version and now I can't update to last version. After `hg update tip` I'm getting this message:

```
abort: untracked file in working directory differs from file in requested
revision: '.DS_Store'
```

I'm new to mercurial. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means that Mercurial is unsure about what to do. You have a file with content `something` in the working copy. The file is not version controlled, so Mercurial will normally leave it alone when you update. However, the revision you're updating to **also** has a file with the same name, and the content **differs** from the `something` you already have in the file.

You can get this problem if you do

```
$ hg init
$ echo "a file" > a
$ hg add a
$ hg commit -m "added a"
$ echo "b file" > b
$ hg add b
$ hg commit -m "added b"
```

You now have two revisions, the latest has files `a` and `b`. If you update back to the first revision and create a different file `b`, then you get trouble:

```
$ hg update 0
$ echo "other b file" > b
$ hg update
abort: untracked file in working directory differs from file in requested
revision: 'b'
```

The normal solution is to commit *before* updating. You should generally not update with a dirty working copy ("dirty" means that `hg status` isn't empty). Mercurial does support such updates, but you should only use them if you know what you're doing.

So to continue the example above we can either commit the new `b` and then merge:

```
$ hg add b
$ hg commit -m "added new b"
$ hg merge
```

This gives a conflict in `b` since the two versions contain `b file` and `other b file`, respectively. Resolve the conflict and commit:

```
$ hg commit -m "merged two bs"
```

An alternative is to delete the file from the working copy. **That is what I'll do in your case:** `.DS_Store` files should not be tracked in the first place. They store some folder information on Mac OS X and this is not part of your source code. So you do

```
$ rm .DS_Store
$ hg update
```

The update resurrected the `.DS_Store` file. You now want to tell Mercurial that it should stop tracking the file:

```
$ hg forget .DS_Store
```

and you also want to tell Mercurial to ignore such files from now on:

```
$ echo "syntax: glob" >> .hgignore
$ echo ".DS_Store" >> .hgignore
$ hg commit -m "removed .DS_Store file, ignored from now on"
```